# Event at the end of DIV with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on this page. Main structure is some DIVs beneath each other. I need to do some transitions or animations when user scrolls from one to another. The height of the DIVs aren't the same. it is done only by min-height:100%. My JS doesn't work when I try to do any alert at the end of the DIV.

```
 <div id="page">
    <div class="section section_1"> ...content...</div>
    <div class="section section_2">...content...</div>
    <div class="section section_3">...content...</div>
    <div class="section section_4">...content...</div>
</div>
```

This is the JS file

```
jQuery(
$('.section').on('scroll', function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
        alert('end of div');
         }
     })

 );
```

Do you have any ideas why this doesn't work? Or can you suggest me any other solution how to make this kind of animation?

Answer (score 2):

[**Code Example for Local**](https://github.com/xenyal/DOMElementViewportTest/blob/master/DOMElementInViewportTest.html)

---

Question's already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport/7557433#7557433).

**Edited**

Bind your `alert` as such:

```
var shown = document.getElementById("page").children;

function callback () {
    alert('end of div');
} 

function isElementInViewport(el) {
    var eap,
        rect     = el.getBoundingClientRect(),
        docEl    = document.documentElement,
        vWidth   = window.innerWidth || docEl.clientWidth,
        vHeight  = window.innerHeight || docEl.clientHeight,
        efp      = function (x, y) { return document.elementFromPoint(x, y) },
        contains = "contains" in el ? "contains" : "compareDocumentPosition",
        has      = contains == "contains" ? 1 : 0x14;
    // Return false if it's not in the viewport
    if (rect.right < 0 || rect.bottom < 0 
            || rect.left > vWidth || rect.top > vHeight)
        return false;
    // Return true if any of its four corners are visible
    return (
          (eap = efp(rect.left,  rect.top)) == el || el[contains](eap) == has
      ||  (eap = efp(rect.right, rect.top)) == el || el[contains](eap) == has
      ||  (eap = efp(rect.right, rect.bottom)) == el || el[contains](eap) == has
      ||  (eap = efp(rect.left,  rect.bottom)) == el || el[contains](eap) == has
    );
}

function fireIfElementVisible (el, callback) {
    return function () {
        if ( isElementInViewport(el) ) {
            callback();
        }
    }
}

var handler = fireIfElementVisible (shown[shown.length - 1], callback);

$(document).on('DOMContentLoaded load resize scroll', handler);
```

Above function will return boolean on whether your element is currently viewable on screen.

Comment: Am I doing something wrong here? http://jsfiddle.net/chfpha7s/14/ I used your code but it's not working.

Comment: `$(window)` will not work on jsfiddle I believe. The result window is an iframe so you scrolling inside that is not acting in the same document object as where the script is. Trying the function locally would work.

Comment: @AdrianM. I put the sample file on my git link at the top. You can run that locally as an example.

Comment: I've tried it, it works but only when i get to the third DIV. even if I extended the height of DIV to see only one on my screen.

Comment: The browser detects the edge of the last `div` on screen.

Comment: I understand but on screen is only the first div

Comment: I just copy & pasted the file from my Git onto a local html file and it works fine. Can you clear your browser cache?

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.section').bind('scroll', function() {
        if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= this.scrollHeight) {
            alert('end reached');
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: I've tried this here: http://jsfiddle.net/chfpha7s/1/ and it is not working as well